# Проблема преобразования double в uint16_t

Tags: c++, visual-studio

На COM порт приходит uint16_t с следующим значением 3E8C.
Формирую строку из этих символов и добавляю точку, получается 3E8.C

Мне известно, что при преобразовании 3E8.C в double, получается число 1000.75
Для того чтобы понять вот ссылка:
https://numsys.ru/
Преобразуйте число 1000.75 из 10-ой системы счисления в 16-ую.

Не могу понять, как преобразовать этот набор символов из HEX в Double.
Из 3E8.C в 1000.75

Спасибо за Ваше время.

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали сделать? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: Ну почему на русском стеке, каждый третий вопрос вида: "Вот, короче, задание. Сделайте его, а я пока пойду сериальчики смотреть"?

Comment: Почитайте про внутреннее представление чисел типа double. Если хотите разобраться, вот вам [статья по этому поводу](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx?printable=true).

Comment: На ком порт приходит два байта 3E 8C. 
Я точно знаю, что устройство шлет число double.
Оно равно 1000.25
Не могу понять, как его преобразовать, в десятичный вид.

Comment: @NewSheriff: Это не double, у double 64 бита, а вы показали только 16.

Comment: @NewSheriff: Узнайте в документации, какой формат приходит.

Comment: Покамест вы можете получить ваши 1000.75 как `0x3E8C / 16`. Но откуда в вашем формате берётся 16, я не знаю.

Comment: @VladD: Я про это и говорю. Что приходит uint16_t, полностью заряженный. 
Его нужно представить, как double. 
При чем я точно знаю что последние 4-е бита они используют для выделения дробной части.
Получается 3E 8.C  
Я преобразую данный набор символов в строку, добавляю точку в нужном месте, но ума не приложу, как теперь это в double преобразовать.

Comment: @NewSheriff: Так вам и не нужно. Если известно, что последние 4 бита — дробная часть, используйте `uint16_t value = ...; double result = (double)value / 16;`. Никаких строк.

Comment: @VladD: Спасибо, сейчас сделаю ответ.
Вроде помогло

Comment: Вопрос перекоткрыт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Преобразование из INT в double
double d = (double)(_value/100);
//Преобразование из double в шестнадцатеричное символьное представление char
uint16_t tmp1 = (uint16_t)(d*16);

// Для заполнения данных используется два байта в сообщении
// (известен адрес начального байта)
m_msg.at(m_num_of_byte) &= uint8_t(~m_mask);
m_msg.at(m_num_of_byte+1) &= uint8_t(~m_mask);
// Сначала помещаем данные первого байта, потом второго.
m_msg.at(m_num_of_byte) = (tmp1 & 0xff00)>>8;
m_msg.at(m_num_of_byte+1) = uint8_t(tmp1 & 0x00ff);
```